# Proving $ \{ x, \{ y \} \} $ does not serve as ordered pair

Tags: set-theory

I am proving that $ \{ x, \{ y \} \} $ is not suitable as a definition of the ordered pair $(x, y)$, because it does not have the ordered pair property. Ordered pair property says that for any sets, $x, y, u, v$ if $\langle x, y\rangle = \langle u, v\rangle$ then $x=u$ and $y = v$. To prove that $ \{ x, \{ y \} \} $ is not suitable as a definition of ordered pair, I should assume that

$$  \{ x, \{ y \} \}  =  \{ u, \{ v \} \} $$

and come up with case where either $ x \ne u $ or $ y \ne v$. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Well, if $x \ne u$ then $x = \{ v\}$, right?

Comment: $$x= \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$$
$$y= \emptyset $$
$$u= \{ \emptyset \}$$
$$v= \{ \emptyset \}$$

Comment: Usually ordered pair is $\{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: @Crostul Why are you answering in a comment?